# No Audio or Video on Lenovo ThinkPad T410

Tags: sound, video, webcam, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Lenovo ThinkPad T410.

The inbuilt webcam is not displaying any video using Cheese. Also I have no sound at all when playing video or audio. When the Ubuntu OS boots up I don't even hear the sound at start up.

Please how do I get Audio and Video to work?

I have checked the Sound settings, and in the hardware type my sound card reads:
`Internal Audio 1 output/1 input - Analog Stereo Duplex`.

Can I please get some assistance with installing the proper drivers or getting both audio and video to work?

Answer (score 2):

I have a T410 too and have no problems with sound, although I can't get the webcam to work  either.

This is probably too obvious, but try turning up the volume using the buttons above the keyboard?  Also unplug headphones/headset to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I could get back the sound by volume-up with the hardware-keys BEFORE bootup of Ubuntu, ie in BIOS.

After I raised the volume there, it worked in Ubuntu too.